# Is there a way to deny creation of web app's without a network rule defined

Tags: azure, policy, azure-policy

I am trying to deny creation of web apps in azure that do not have network rules defined.

I am trying to using Azure Policy for this, but am unable to get the policy to work. I have identified the policy aliases that hold the configuration in Azure:

```
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.ipSecurityRestrictions[*].vnetSubnetResourceId
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.ipSecurityRestrictions[*].vnetTrafficTag
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.ipSecurityRestrictions[*].subnetTrafficTag
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.ipSecurityRestrictions[*].action
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.ipSecurityRestrictions[*].tag
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.ipSecurityRestrictions[*].priority
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.ipSecurityRestrictions[*].name
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.ipSecurityRestrictions[*].description
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.scmIpSecurityRestrictions[*].ipAddress
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.scmIpSecurityRestrictions[*].subnetMask
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.scmIpSecurityRestrictions[*].vnetSubnetResourceId
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.scmIpSecurityRestrictions[*].vnetTrafficTag
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.scmIpSecurityRestrictions[*].subnetTrafficTag
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.scmIpSecurityRestrictions[*].action
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.scmIpSecurityRestrictions[*].tag
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.scmIpSecurityRestrictions[*].priority
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.scmIpSecurityRestrictions[*].name
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.scmIpSecurityRestrictions[*].description                  
Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.scmIpSecurityRestrictions[*]
```

But the policy that I have tride does not work, this is the latest iteration:

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.ipSecurityRestrictions[*].action",
            "equals": "deny"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

I am trying to look in the array for a "deny" action, if this is defined then no action is needed, else deny. But the policy does nothing, I can deploy web app with and without network rules.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure top level resources are modeled as smaller micro-resources that work together and create a functional end resource. In your case a website will belong to Microsft.Web/sites micro-resource type, but the configuration will be in another micro-resource type called Microsoft.Web/sites/config.

Azure policy only helps you if you're working on a single micro-resource type. The micro resource types are deployed and created asynchronously so there is no way to deny one based on the other at the moment.

You can write a similar policy using auditIfNotExists which has the capability of auditing a micro-resource based on the properties of another.

PS: I'm making up the micro-resource terminology here to clearly communicate the problem, in Azure every one of these are defined as a *resource*.

Checkout the auditIfNotExist docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#auditifnotexists

Your solution would look similar to this (not tested)

```
{
"if": {
    "field": "type",
    "equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
},
"then": {
    "effect": "auditIfNotExists",
    "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
        "existenceCondition": {
            {
                "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.ipSecurityRestrictions[*].action",
                "equals": "deny"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}